# Trusted GPG certificate

Tags: ssl, gnupg, pgp, ca

I have a small question about GPG certificates and certificates authorities.

I am using GnuPG to sign a tarball that I am hosting on my server. I would like that users who wants to download this tarball to be able to encrypt it using my public key.
At the moment, I'm storing my public key on another server that I own. There are 2 issues with this:

- The key isn't "trusted", and the user get a warning
- In the same idea, because the key isn't trusted, if the key is maliciously changed, the user won't see anything

I've read a bit about cryptography solutions in the past, and know a little bit how X.509 CA work, but I don't really understand how it is for PGP keys. I've tried to use my SSL (trusted) certificate in GPG, but it always fails (maybe there is an option I haven't found?).
If it's not possible to use my SSL certificate, how can I "register" my PGP certificate to a CA?

Thanks!

Best,
Thibault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[For all practical purposes, X.509 certificates and OpenPGP key pairs live in separate worlds](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47336/120885). X.509 certificates are trusted hierarchically (building certificate chains) and OpenPGP keys are trusted on peer-to-peer basis.

As the technologies are incompatible, they are not easily replaceable by each other. To let users trust your OpenPGP key, you can publish it in one of OpenPPG key repositories (keyservers), and hope (or suggest) that users do use it as a trusted source of OpenPGP keys.

Alternatively, you can use your server's certificate to create a detached PKCS#7/CMS signature of the archive you distribute, but unlike OpenPGP there are no widespread tools available to check PKCS#7/CMS signatures on end-user computers. (Well, maybe OpenSSL will work for your user audience.) Note that KeyUsage of the server's certificate probably won't be appropriate for signing, so the users will get a warning.

Please note that OpenPGP keys are called "keys", and X.509 certificates are called in this way too. There exist no "pgp certificates" as well as no "ssl certificates".

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting answer. I will look at how I could publish my key on a key repository. Thanks for the terms disambiguation as well ;)

Comment: Just one additional question. I've put my public key there: http://pgp.mit.edu/ . Is this all I need to do? GPG will automatically know where to search in the CA? - I don't understand one thing, if an attacker changes the key on the server where the public key is located, then the problem is still the same..

Comment: No, just putting is not enough - as I mentioned, the users must trust and use that server. "Trust" means that the server must be secure (eg. you need to prove possession of the private key when putting the key to the server) and that users know this server and can/want to take public keys from there.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. However, there is still one thing I don't understand. I am building this setup in the situation au automated updates. Thus, I am managing the decryption phase myself. This said, I could set the server I want as "trusted", but my concern is 1- how to prove possession of the private key? 2- more specifically, how can I be sure that the key hasn't been changed, from a user-side (in an automated process) ? - In simple words, is there any secured server I could use to upload my public key, and download it on the client side, being sure of the key?

Comment: I don't know any particular URLs of the servers to give you. Building trust relationships is one of the most complicated tasks in both PKI and OpenPGP.

Comment: Thanks, then the question is still open.

Comment: For "trusted server" question I'd suggest asking a separate question, because this question in its current form doesn't mention such servers. Also with the way StackOverflow works this question already saw his best day yesterday and unless you offer a bounty (for which you don't have reputation) it won't have much more exposure. On the other hand, looking for a trusted PGP server is off-topic according to current SO rules ("asking to recommend favorite site or resource").